# module not found firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

*Failed to compile.
./node_modules/firebase/firebase-analytics.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-app.js' in '/Users/auser/Documents/react/img-sharing-app/node_modules/firebase'*

I have deleted my .../node_modules and I executed de novo *npm install*
My index.js file has added exactly copy/paste from the firebase console :

```
    '''
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
       // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

     // Your web app's Firebase configuration
     const firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "**************************",
     authDomain: "**********************",
     projectId: "******************",
     storageBucket: "**********************",
     messagingSenderId: "*********************",
     appId: "*****************************"
    };

 // Initialize Firebase
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);'''
```

Important note: I do not have the analytics enabled in my firebase project.
I also tried previously, for the same project to have google analytics enabled , but I got the exactly the same  error of  ~~~modude not found

Comment: uncomment your import lines, you need to import it before it works

Comment: This line is uncommented : import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app

Comment: Curiously, adding the same firebase app script to a brand new react project, '''const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);'''  works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new react app and I copied
from the new package.json
*"dependencies": {

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
"firebase": "^9.6.9",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.0",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
```

},*
section and replace into the old react project.
Then I did *npm install*. Finally, npm start rendered the app in the browser [ =>the error disappeared ]